# mongodb updateMany query filter and update race conditions?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.collection.updateMany(filter, update, options)
```

The `updateMany` takes in a query filter. Suppose this query filter returns 5 documents to update. Then this operation will try to update these 5 documents. If another thread (in the meantime, after this `updateMany's` query filter has run and returned 5 documents for it to update ):

1. Updates one or more of these 5 documents then when this updateMany
   tries to update there would be an error returned?
2. Deletes one of these documents then when this updateMany tries to update there
   would be an error returned?
3. Inserts another record that matches the query filter of this updateMany then that record would not be updated by this operation?

IS my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb official documentation about the consistency answers your question.

The example is exactly about the `updateMany` command.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#read-uncommitted-and-multiple-document-write